# close socket from client so that asyncore server detects it

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, tcp, asyncore

I am building a chat server client system. a socket is created at the client side to connect to the server listening at a port. The problem is when I try to close the socket from the client side, the asyncore handle_close does not detect it.

Server code:

```
clients = {}
identity={}
class MainServerSocket(asyncore.dispatcher):
def __init__(self, port):
    asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self)
    self.create_socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    self.bind(('',port))
    self.listen(5)
def handle_accept(self):
    newSocket, address = self.accept( )
    clients[address] = newSocket
    #try : 
        #hndl=newSocket.recv(1024)
        #print "Connected from", address,hndl
    #except : 
        #e = sys.exc_info()[1]
    print "Connected from", address
    handler=SecondaryServerSocket(newSocket)
    handler.setAddr(address)
    every = clients.values()
    for one in every:
        one.send('Server message:'+str(address)+' joined'+'\n')

class SecondaryServerSocket(asyncore.dispatcher_with_send):
def setAddr(self, addr):
    self.addr = addr

def isid(self,txt):
    pattern=re.compile('\*\$\$\$\*(.+)\*\$\$\$\*')
    match=pattern.search(txt)
    rv=0
    if match :
        self.hndl=match.group(1)
        rv=1
        if self.hndl not in identity.values():
            identity[self.addr]=self.hndl 
            every=clients.values()
            for one in every:
                one.send('Server message:'+str(self.addr)+' is known as '+self.hndl+'\n')
        else:
            clients[self.addr].send("Server message: handle in use, retry. Disconnecting.")
            self.close()
    return rv    #del clients[self.addr]    
def handle_read(self):
    receivedData = self.recv(8192)
    if receivedData:
        if not self.isid(receivedData):
        #self.addr
            every = clients.values()
            for one in every:
                one.send(receivedData)
    else: self.close( )
def handle_close(self):
    print "Disconnected from", self.getpeername( )

    one = self.getpeername( )
    del identity[one]
    del clients[one]
    every=clients.values()
    try:    
        for one in every:
            one.send('server message:'+str(self.addr)+' quit'+'\n')
    except: pass
print "server started"
MainServerSocket(21567)
asyncore.loop( )
```

client code(relevant bits):

```
    class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.serv_ip=StringVar()
        self.port=StringVar()
        self.handle=StringVar()
        self.serv_ip.set('127.0.0.1')
        self.port.set('21567')
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()
        self.lastname=""
        self.currentname=""
        self.delim=('-'*45)+'\n'
    def connect(self):
        if len(self.handle.get())>0 and not self.handle.get().isspace() :
            HOST = self.serv_ip.get()
            PORT = int(self.port.get())
            #BUFSIZE = 1024
            ADDR = (HOST, PORT)
            try:
                self.tcpCliSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
                self.tcpCliSock.connect(ADDR)
                idtext='*$$$*'+self.handle.get()+'*$$$*'
                self.tcpCliSock.send(idtext)
                self.add("sys message: CONNECTED TO "+str(HOST)+':'+str(PORT)+'\n')
                self.socket()
                self.con_button.configure(text="DISCONNECT!",command=self.disconnect)
                self.entry_field.configure(state=NORMAL)
                self.handle_entry.configure(state=DISABLED)
            except: 
                e = sys.exc_info()[1]
                self.add("sys message: ERROR CONNECTING to "+str(HOST)+':'+str(PORT)+"   "+str(e)+'\n')
                #pass
        else : self.add("sys message: Enter handle/nickname and try again."+'\n')

    def disconnect(self):
        #try : self.tcpCliSock.shutdown(2)
        #except: pass
        #self.tcpCliSock.close()
        self.tcpCliSock.send('')
        self.tcpCliSock.close()
        self.closeflag=1
        self.add("sys message: Disconnected."+'\n')
        self.con_button.configure(text="CONNECT!",command=self.connect)
        self.entry_field.configure(state=DISABLED)
        self.handle_entry.configure(state=NORMAL)
        self.closeflag=0
        #self.send_button.configure(state=DISABLED)

    def socket(self):
    def loop0():
        while 1:
            try:
                if self.closeflag==0: 
                    data = self.tcpCliSock.recv(BUFSIZE)

                    if data: self.add(data)
            except:
                e = sys.exc_info()[1]
                self.add("ERROR: "+str(e)+'  disconnecting...'+'\n')
                self.con_button.configure(text="CONNECT!",command=self.connect)
                self.entry_field.configure(state=DISABLED)
                self.handle_entry.configure(state=NORMAL)
                self.closeflag=0
                thread.exit()
                #self.disconnect()
                break
            if self.closeflag==1 :
                self.tcpCliSock.close()
                print "ping"
                thread.exit()

    thread.start_new_thread(loop0, ())
```

I know this is a lot of code but I am not sure which bit is causing the problems so decided to add all the parts I think could be responsible.when the disconnect function is called, the server doesnt detect a disconnection. And then after the disconnect, the connect function is called, then the client crashes.